# How can I tell who posted a photo in a shared iCloud photo stream?

Tags: icloud, photo-stream

Can you determine which/whose device took a picture in a shared iPhone photo stream?

Answer (score 4):

Open the photo in the Shared Photo Stream, then tap to show details if necessary.

It should show the poster of the photo, as below ("Posted by you"):

[image: Like | Posted by you | Add a comment…]

Individual devices can't be determined from this view though — only the Apple ID.